# Synchronizing Hibernate persistence + Spring AMQP publish transactions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-amqp

In my application a user creates a post which gets persisted in the db + published to a Spring amqp queue

When the user creates a post flow hits the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createPost", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", 
            produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Post createUserPost(@RequestBody(required=false) Post post, Principal principal){
        this.userService.persistPost(post);
        logger.info("post persistance successful");
        publishService.publishUserPosts(post);
        return post;
    }
```

There are two services `persistPost` & `publishUserPosts` in different Service classes called in the controller.

**Publish Service**

```
@Transactional
    public void publishUserPosts(Post post){
        try{
            logger.info("Sending user post to the subscribers");
            amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(post);
            }catch(AmqpException e){
                throw new MyAppException(e);
            }
    }
```

The problem is both service calls are running under different transactions. If the `PublishPost` transaction fails the post is still persisted in the db.

To bring both the services under a single transaction I've changed the code & injected the `persistPost` service in `PublishPost` class.

```
@Transactional
    public void publishUserPosts(Post post){
        try{
            userService.persistPost(post);
            logger.info("post persistance successful");
            logger.info("Sending user post to the subscribers");
            amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(post);
            }catch(AmqpException e){
                throw new MyAppException(e);
            }
    }
```

**My question**

Is this the best approach to achieve multiple services under a single transaction or I can do better with some other approach?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using JTA? Otherwise the transaction you are using to send the message is not really doing anything.

Comment: I am using the HibernateTransactionManager. I have tested the code, transaction works fine, just need to confirm the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confused about how transactions works. The `HiberanteTransactionManager` can only deal with database operations. To make other parts transactional too, such as messaging, you must use technology called Java Transactional API (JTA), whichs allows to *merge* transactions of different technologies into one big *distributed* transaction. In Spring, this is provided by the [JTATransactionManage](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html).

Regardless of the above, the more accepted design in this case (if you follow Domain-Driven Design patterns) is to have one [Application Service](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/characterization.html#Services) which acts as a facade to your domain and is responsible for keeping the transactional boundary. This Application Service then calls the [Post Repository](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/characterization.html#Repositories) (what you called `userService`) and finally publishes the message. So in pseudo code

```
class PostApplicationService {
   @Transactional
   public void publishUserPosts(Post post){
      postRepository.save(post);
      publishService.notifyNewPost(post);
   }
}
```

And I would do the notification using an local event bus (such as the one provided by Spring or Guava). But that is just my preference :).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Augusto, I have implemented transactions as per the Spring AMQP doc, RabbitMQ doesn't support distributed transactions. So I am following the Best effort 1PC one phase commit pattern, using the hibernate transaction manager. I've even checked in the logs, the message sender & listener container are covered by the HibernateTransactionManager. As per the docs @Transactional works fine with messaging its just we require a channel supporting transactions. Also I am thinking of using server sent events for sending the notification for a new post to the browser.